# IBM Watson Assistant: How to add more then 5 skills?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I need to add more than 5 skills in Watson Assistant, but I don't know how to add them.

I have a Plus plan with 100 assistants and 5 skills. When I add 5 skills in 5 assistants, the system responds "You have limit 5 skills". How can I use the other 95 assistants?

Answer (score 0):

See the [pricing and plan overview for IBM Watson Assistant](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/watson-assistant/pricing/) for how many skills can be created in each service plan. The documentation details [how to add skills to an assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-skill-add).

A dialog skill defines the intents, entities and the dialog structure. A search skill can be used for integrating IBM Watson Discovery. Once you have skills defined, typically only a single dialog skill, you add them to an assistant. The assistant is the wrapper around the skill for building the chatbot and integrating it into a website, Slack or Facebook Messenger or hooking it up with a phone system.

You say that you have a Plus plan. Note that the docs point out restrictions for the "Plus Trial" plan which only has 5 skills.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new resource group.
Then choose this new resource group while creating the new service.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community: For anyone who is familiar with Watson Assistant, they would certainly understand this response. If I was the questioner, I would regard this a very spot on answer. I have faced this problem myself and did not know the solution for months. I have been working with Watson Assistant for 4.5 years, and I know what I'm talking about. There is another elaborate response from another user here that doesn't address the question at all. If a real user asks for more details, I would definitely provide more details.